# (closing } without matching opening { ) error in KDB when writing function

Tags: function, syntax-error, kdb

I just started learning KDB on my own two days ago, so this could be a bit naïve.

I am trying to write a function which takes one input which is a table and one which is a symbol (a stock ticker). I hope to be able to use this function to eventually iterate over a list:

table {function}/ (list of symbols)

However, in writing the function, I get an error. The function looks like this:

```
/H is a table, y is a symbol. 

suffering:{[H,y] quotes: asdf (`.ceq.getQuotes;y; 2016.01.04; 14:41; 2016.01.29; 21:18;(`source`applyca`fungible`tz)!(`exegy; 0b; `officialConsolidated ;`$"America/New_York"));
w:  select from aj [`date ; select OrderId, Side, Price,Market, ltime date+time from execs where RIC= y;update date:time from quotes ];
c:select date, Market, LPrice:log Price from w;
n1: select from aj[`date`Market; c; w];
n1:update realdate:`date$date from n1;
n1:update delta:{0,1_deltas x}LPrice by realdate from n1; 
agg:n,n1;
argh:select goodbp: avg delta by sym from agg where bsize >asize, Side = "1";
asf:select badbp:avg delta by sym from agg where bsize < asize, Side = "1";
poof: ej[`sym;argh;asf];
H:H, poof}
```

As far as I can see, this follows the syntax just fine: the arguments are separated by semicolons, the parameters are in brackets, etc.

Is it that I can't have a table as an input? Why am I getting this error:

"(closing } without matching opening { ) "

when the function does indeed have a matching opening {

Comment: input parameter are separated by semicolon and not comma.  Change it to -> suffering:{[H;y]  . That will fix the error

Comment: Also indent your code. That could also give no matching { error

Comment: Thanks so much Rahul! Side question: if I named a list of stocks "things", would TABLE: suffering over things let me loop through everything, or would I have to individually list the list of stocks?

Comment: Will work but result will vary depending on how you order your arguments. So understand the over behavior. you can use something like TABLE suffering/ things

Answer (score 1):

When your function definition spans multiple lines, each continuation line must start with one or more space characters.  For example:

```
f:{
  x+y}
```

is correct, but

```
g:{
x+y}
```

is two syntax errors because q processes the two lines separately and the first line lacks a closing } while the second lacks an opening {.

See [Starting kdb+ / Scripts](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Startingkdbplus/qlanguage#2.9_Scripts) for details.